# Is ImmutableCollection.contains() case-sensitive?

Tags: java

When `.contains()` is called on an ImmutableSet of Strings, is the comparison case-sensitive?  In the sample code below, will the parameter `key` of "foo", "Foo", and "FOO" all return false?

```
public class MyClass {
  public static final String FOO_KEY = "foo";
  public static final String BAR_KEY = "bar";

  static final ImmutableSet<String> RESERVED_KEYS = new ImmutableSet.Builder<String>()
    .add(FOO_KEY)
    .add(BAR_KEY)
    .build();

  public boolean validate(String key) {
    if (RESERVED_KEYS.contains(key)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Downvoter: the Javadoc doesn't mention case-sensitivity. https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: agreed, it doesn't mention the implementation of equality; updated my post to include the iterators.contains() source code, please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: All collections in java use the equals contact unless explicitly specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's case sensitive, because it is based on the `equals()` method of `Object` rather than the case-insensitive `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` method.

You'll need to perform case-folding yourself when inserting and testing elements.

Comment: I think the solution from Premraj is more what people are looking for. Use a ImmutableSortedSet and specify string case-insensitivity for the comparator.

Answer (score 1):

So if you check out the [source code](https://code.google.com/r/baggiogamp-guava/source/browse/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.java?spec=svn4fdf70002a73087bcb94ac0619f819bbc6c035d8&name=release08&r=4fdf70002a73087bcb94ac0619f819bbc6c035d8), here is what the .contains() looks like:

```
public boolean contains(@Nullable Object object) {
    return object != null && Iterators.contains(iterator(), object);
}
```

Here, you'll notice Iterators.contains() is [defined](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html) as:

```
     Returns true if iterator contains element.
```

Here is the source code for Iterators.contains()

```
   public static boolean contains(Iterator<?> iterator, @Nullable Object element)
   {
     if (element == null) {
     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      if (iterator.next() == null) {
        return true;
      }
   }
} else {
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (element.equals(iterator.next())) {
       return true;
     }
   }
 }
 return false;
 }
```

Here, the .equals() method is used, and since you're passing in a string-it would behave the same as if you were to call "Foo".equals("foo");

You can find Iterators source code [here](https://code.google.com/r/baggiogamp-guava/source/browse/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.java?spec=svn91c77c074eb325b601071516cd98514cd1b9d355&name=release07&r=91c77c074eb325b601071516cd98514cd1b9d355).

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

Some java collections uses `Comparator` instead of `equals`. Ideally `compare` method should be consistent with `equals` but Strings are special case ;-)

You can use this to your benefit (only in such cases) to perform case insensitive checks. Just change `ImmutableSet` to `ImmutableSortedSet` and rest of the code should work as is.

So your class will look like -

```
public static class MyClass {
        public static final String FOO_KEY = "foo";
        public static final String BAR_KEY = "bar";

        final ImmutableSortedSet<String> RESERVED_KEYS =
                ImmutableSortedSet.orderedBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
                        .add(FOO_KEY)
                        .add(BAR_KEY)
                        .build();

        public boolean validate(String key) {
            return !RESERVED_KEYS.contains(key);
        }
    }
```